# MS access database Java

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I am using `MS Access` database with my Java application. The application gets the connection from the database for every 2 minutes and closes the connection after one minute and repeats this all day.

Does it affect(corrupt/crash) the database if I use this kind of methods where the values will change everytime?

Sample code

```
public void someMethod() {
    String update = "UPDATE SETTINGS SET Rem_Date = ?, Rem_Count = ?";
    try
    {
        conn = ac.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(update);
        stmt.setDate(1, differentDate); //date will change here for every loop
        stmt.setInt(2, num); //value will change here for every loop
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException ex){}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}

    finally
    {
        if(stmt != null) {stmt.close();}
        if(conn != null) {conn.close();}
    }
}
```

And if I call this method for every two minutes

```
while(for every two minutes) {
    someMethod(); 
}
```

Comment: *Does it effect the DB?* I don't understand what you mean by this, sorry.

Comment: Effect the database in what sense? It updates the DB with the same count always, which is pretty useless and today(going by the naming convention) will be the same for 24hrs and will change only when the date changes. So you're doing unnecessary updates, IMHO.

Comment: How about using a single or pooled connection? I think opening and closing connections to databases may cause some overhead. So its definitely not advised.

Comment: I hardly think that updating your database with a single query every 2 minutes will have any significant performance impact.

Comment: Didn't get your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, my question was if I have method like above with different values changing all the time, will there be any affect like corrupt or crashed by opening and closing it for every 2 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. It probably will not corrupt the database.**

If it would, the whole database would be unstable, independent of the frequency of updates.

If this crashed, it would also crash if the update interval was 5 days (though it would probably longer to show symptoms).